# How to get the Bearer Auth token before sending the request using HttpInterceptor in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I use Ionic 4 to create an app. I try to implement an HttpInterceptor to add the Bearer Authorization token to requests.

**Problem**: the request is sent before the token is read

More details:

1. I try to read the token from local storage
2. The *console.log* below prints outs the token

What is wrong ?

```
import {HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent,HttpInterceptor,HttpResponse,HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    token:any;

    constructor(private router: Router,private storage: Storage) {
        this.storage.get('User').then((val) => {
            this.token = val;
            console.log(val); // Returns the token
        });
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

      console.log(this.token); // Returns undefined
      if (this.token) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            'Authorization': this.token
          }
        });
      }

      if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
      }

      request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
      });

      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            console.log('event--->>>', event);
          }
          return event;
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            if (error.error.success === false) {
              // this.presentToast('Login failed');
            } else {
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
          }
          return throwError(error);
        }));
    }

}
```

Comment: I am curious, if you put a console.log('{CODE_LOCATION}' + this.token) in both the constructor and the intercept function, does that return your token?

Comment: @dmoore1181 It returns it for the constructor but it's undefined in the intercept function. I updated the question.

Comment: I just simply suggest advanced http plugin use for all http requests.
 https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calls to the storage return a Promise and are therefore async. Get the token inside the intercept function. Since the intercept function wants an Observable, convert the storage call with RxJS:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    return from(this.storage.get('User')).pipe(
        mergeMap((val) => {
            // clone and modify the request
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: val
                }
            });
            [...more stuff you want]
            return next.handle(request);
        });
     )
}
```

I did not test this function but I hope you get the idea. Maybe add an if else statement and the token as local variable to not read it from the storage every call.

```
token:string;
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if(!this.token)
    return from(this.storage.get('User')).pipe(
        mergeMap((val) => {
            this.token = val
            [... modify and return request headers like above]
        })
    )
    else{ 
        [... use this.token for headers ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I get Object(...)(...).mergeMap is not a function and Property mergeMap does not exists on type Observable<any>

Comment: @LucienDubois sorry that was for an older rxjs version. I updated the answer for rxjs 6. You have to use .pipe(mergeMap(...)) in this case